# How can I tell if I need to upgrade/replace Macbook 07 Airport card?

Tags: wifi, upgrade, airport

I bought a used Macbook (late 07 model, white, 2.1 Intel Core Duo, 3 gig RAM) and I have been upgrading everything I can. It works great EXCEPT the airport card. The wireless internet is so slow! When I plug it in to the LAN line it's as fast as can be. When I go into "About this Mac" and pull up the airport card info it lists the card as "AirPort Extreme  (0x14E4, 0x88)". I am trying to figure out if the card is messed up and needs to be replaced/upgraded. Are there any tests for this? Is the card old enough that it just can't handle "modern" internet speeds or should it be the same as LAN speeds because right now trying to check my email or facebook reminds me of the dial up days... So I have had it plugged into LAN since I have got it but that is not an option once I start school back up... Thanks!